# ESP32 handle webserver and neopixels (with delay) in two cores

Tags: arduino, webserver, esp8266, esp32

I'm searching the answer for a while but haven't found how to fix this problem. I have a lot of neopixel animations (currently 50 of them), these are written with delays which keeps the animations simple and readable. disadvantage is the delays as you all know. 50 animations to rewrite is a hell of a job so I want to avoid this. What I did is bought an ESP32 with two cores, so I thought I could run the animations on one core and the webserver on one core. previously I wanted to do I with an interrupt on a ESP8266 but I red and tested that I was not possible to do communication things or run a webserver in an interrupt for example. Is it possible to do that with two cores on an ESP32 or am I running in to the same problem as earlier? current output of the program: My webserver starts and the neopixel animation is showed when pushing the button, however my webserver continuously restarts over and over again. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

ps: In the worst case scenario I have to rewrite my animations, anyone an idea how to replace 3 for loops in to non blocking code?

code running on ESP32:

```
TaskHandle_t Task1;
TaskHandle_t Task2;


#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 6
  #define NUM_LEDS 24
  // Parameter 1 = number of pixels in strip
  // Parameter 2 = pin number (most are valid)
  // Parameter 3 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
  //   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
  //   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
  //   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
  //   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not v2)
  Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUM_LEDS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);


void colorWipe(byte red, byte green, byte blue, int SpeedDelay) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      setPixel(i, red, green, blue);
      showStrip();
      delay(SpeedDelay);
  }
}
// *** REPLACE TO HERE ***

void showStrip() {
 #ifdef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H 
   // NeoPixel
   strip.show();
 #endif
 #ifndef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H
   // FastLED
   FastLED.show();
 #endif
}

void setPixel(int Pixel, byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
 #ifdef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H 
   // NeoPixel
   strip.setPixelColor(Pixel, strip.Color(red, green, blue));
 #endif
 #ifndef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H 
   // FastLED
   leds[Pixel].r = red;
   leds[Pixel].g = green;
   leds[Pixel].b = blue;
 #endif
}

void setAll(byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++ ) {
    setPixel(i, red, green, blue); 
  }
  showStrip();
}



#include <WiFi.h>

const char* WIFI_NAME= "xxxxxxxxxx"; 
const char* WIFI_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxx"; 
WiFiServer server(80);

String header;

// Auxiliary variables to store the current output state
String output5State = "off";
String output4State = "off";

// Assign output variables to GPIO pins
const int output5 = 2;
const int output4 = 4;

// Current time
unsigned long currentTime = millis();
// Previous time
unsigned long previousTime = 0; 
// Define timeout time in milliseconds (example: 2000ms = 2s)
const long timeoutTime = 2000;

String ledState = "off";


void setup() {


 //create a task that will be executed in the Task1code() function, with priority 1 and executed on core 0
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
                  Task1code,   /* Task function. */
                  "Task1",     /* name of task. */
                  10000,       /* Stack size of task */
                  NULL,        /* parameter of the task */
                  1,           /* priority of the task */
                  &Task1,      /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
                  0);          /* pin task to core 0 */                  
delay(500); 

//create a task that will be executed in the Task2code() function, with priority 1 and executed on core 1
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
                  Task2code,   /* Task function. */
                  "Task2",     /* name of task. */
                  10000,       /* Stack size of task */
                  NULL,        /* parameter of the task */
                  1,           /* priority of the task */
                  &Task2,      /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
                  1);          /* pin task to core 1 */
  delay(500); 

  
Serial.begin(115200);


 // Initialize the output variables as outputs
  pinMode(output5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output4, OUTPUT);
  // Set outputs to LOW
  digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output4, LOW);



}


//Task1code: blinks an LED every 1000 ms
void Task1code( void * pvParameters ){
  Serial.print("Task1 running on core ");
  Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());

  
  
    strip.begin();
    strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

  for(;;){
    /*
    digitalWrite(output5, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
    delay(1000);*/

    //Serial.print("state:" + ledState);
    if(ledState == "on") {
      //digitalWrite(output4, HIGH);
      colorWipe(0x00,0xff,0x00, 50);
      colorWipe(0x00,0x00,0x00, 50);
    } else {
      strip.clear();
       strip.show();
    }
  } 

  
}

//Task2code: blinks an LED every 700 ms
void Task2code( void * pvParameters ){

 Serial.print("Connecting to ");
Serial.println(WIFI_NAME);
WiFi.begin(WIFI_NAME, WIFI_PASSWORD);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(1000);
Serial.print("Trying to connect to Wifi Network");
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Successfully connected to WiFi network");
Serial.println("IP address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
server.begin();

  for(;;){
      WiFiClient client = server.available(); 
if (client) { 

Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    currentTime = millis();
    previousTime = currentTime;
    while (client.connected() && currentTime - previousTime <= timeoutTime) { // loop while the client's connected
      currentTime = millis();         
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            
            // turns the GPIOs on and off
            if (header.indexOf("GET /5/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 5 on");
              output5State = "on";
              
              //digitalWrite(output5, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /5/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 5 off");
              output5State = "off";
              
              //digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /4/on") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 4 on");
              output4State = "on";
              ledState = "on";
              //digitalWrite(output4, HIGH);
            } else if (header.indexOf("GET /4/off") >= 0) {
              Serial.println("GPIO 4 off");
              output4State = "off";
              ledState = "off";
              //digitalWrite(output4, LOW);
            }
            
            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            // CSS to style the on/off buttons 
            // Feel free to change the background-color and font-size attributes to fit your preferences
            client.println("<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}");
            client.println(".button { background-color: #195B6A; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;");
            client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
            client.println(".button2 {background-color: #77878A;}</style></head>");
            
            // Web Page Heading
            client.println("<body><h1>ESP8266 Web Server</h1>");
            
            // Display current state, and ON/OFF buttons for GPIO 5  
            client.println("<p>GPIO 5 - State " + output5State + "</p>");
            // If the output5State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (output5State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/5/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/5/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            } 
               
            // Display current state, and ON/OFF buttons for GPIO 4  
            client.println("<p>GPIO 4 - State " + output4State + "</p>");
            // If the output4State is off, it displays the ON button       
            if (output4State=="off") {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/4/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a></p>");
            } else {
              client.println("<p><a href=\"/4/off\"><button class=\"button button2\">OFF</button></a></p>");
            }
            client.println("</body></html>");
            
            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line
            client.println();
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
    
}
  }
}


void loop(){

}
```

animation with three for loops:

```
void theaterChaseRainbow(int SpeedDelay) { /* for wheel watch higher in the code */
  byte *c;
  
  for (int j=0; j < 256; j++) {     // cycle all 256 colors in the wheel
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
        for (int i=0; i < NUM_LEDS; i=i+3) {
          c = Wheels( (i+j) % 255);
          setPixel(i+q, *c, *(c+1), *(c+2));    //turn every third pixel on
        }
        showStrip();
       
        delay(SpeedDelay);
       
        for (int i=0; i < NUM_LEDS; i=i+3) {
          setPixel(i+q, 0,0,0);        //turn every third pixel off
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in arduino, wifi stuff runs on the "2nd" core by default, without messing around with tasks or semaphores. you can't do two userland things at once. I have turned some light effects into async the same as you're asking about. The basic idea is that you make the loop counters global and kill the for loops. replace the inner loop body with a function called next(), which is called each time in loop(). you'll have to handle the variable increments and rollovers in next(), which is some work, but not hard. You might also have to return early if next() fires too often, since you have no delay()...

Comment: for the chasers code shown, you'll also need a mode global boolean variable, which you flip as needed to run only the first half or 2nd half, typically when an incrementor overflows.

Answer (score 0):

You're 95% of the way there. ESP32 runs FreeRTOS with preemptive multi-threading. Your code is quite reasonably divided into two threads (Task1 and Task2) which run on different cores. In fact, the number of cores doesn't really matter much as long as you're not running out of CPU cycles or violating the real-time deadlines of your animations. You could probably run both tasks concurrently on a single core without the ESP32 breaking a sweat.

As for the HTTP server restarting - that's the intended behaviour of your code, is it not? The (rather horribly indented) function Task2code runs a never-ending loop which starts the HTTP server, serves a page and the stops. Is this loop really necessary?